# Is there a way to override the system defined color value in CSS?

Tags: css

I'd like `color: red` to automatically be rendered as `color: #DB0000` by the browser. Instead of setting the style for "red" in our application as `color: red`, I want to use a different color than the system-defined definition of red. Our application uses a different "red" color than the standard setting for setting the `color: red` style in css. Other than creating a class and using that class where I need to set the style (I'm afraid developers could forget to use this class and instead set `color: red`), is there a way to automatically override the defined color for `color: red` and override it with my own setting of `color: #DB0000`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

<del>That's not possible with CSS, but if you use SASS, you can create a macro to change the color, although that still might not work.</del>

***EDIT:*** After doing some spelunking on my own, there *is* a way to use variables in pure CSS (no SASS!):

```css
:root {
    --red: #DB0000; /* Define your custom value */
}

p {
    color: var(--red); /* Reference your custom value.
                         All <p> elements will be given
                         a text color of #DB0000 */
}
```

Check out this [CodePen](https://codepen.io/20avva/pen/QZmjbe)

Source: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/Using_CSS_variables

Answer (score 5):

No, there isn't a possibility like this in plain CSS.

However, in SASS and LESS (both CSS preprocessors) you can define varibles. So you can for example define `@red1: #DB0000` as a variable and later on use `color: @red1` or `border-color: @red1` in as many CSS rules as you like.

Comment: Technically there is something like this in plain CSS: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/Using_CSS_variables -it's just not fully supported across all browsers.

Comment: yes, I know, but for now you'd need a time machine that moves you two years into the future in order to have realistic browser support...

Comment: I mean, support isn't too awful, depending on what browsers you're targeting: http://caniuse.com/#search=css%20var() .. but I agree SASS/LESS is a better way to go.